# count nodes of two different content type in rules

Tags: rules

I need to use rule module and count nodes of a content type A, then count nodes of content type B and after that if count of nodes A is higher of count of nodes B do an action, otherwise do another action. What i need to do for achieve that?

Comment: Interface it with Views using Views Bonus Pack or Views Bulk Operations. Then let views do the counting for you (an aggregated view that COUNT by content type) and let rules get the view result. And you might consider installing Conditional Rules for more better conditional rule branching

Comment: I meant Rules Bonus Pack.

Comment: Solved with this module https://www.drupal.org/node/1600272 and view rules/VBO